# Do you still use DXSDK_DIR in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, directx

I am aware that with Windows 7, after you install the DirectX SDK, you can add a reference to this in a project by adding **$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;** to the **Include Directories** textbox under **VC++ Directories** in your projects property dialogue box.

I am also aware that on Windows 8, there is no longer a Direct X SDK. Everything you need is bundled into the Windows 8 SDK, so my question is on Windows 8, what do I need to add to the **Include Directories** textbox under **VC++ Directories** in a projects property dialogue box to use DirectX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The platform SDK is already in the VC++ list, so there's nothing to add. If it doesn't compile, you may have installed the new SDK alongside the old, without updating the location in VC++.

Comment: This is if you have VC 2012, but if you have 2010 or lower you would want to include the directory <Program Files x86>\Windows Kits\8.0\Includes, to use the new DirectX. If you do not it will use the one under <Program Files x86>\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include (for VS 2010)